# Удачи(,) и да поможет вам Бог!

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая в следующем предложении: Удачи(,) и да поможет вам Бог!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Удачи, и да поможет вам Бог!***

Два совершенно разных по структуре предложения. Первое предложение неполное, второе побудительное.

Частица ДА: 11. (в сочет. с глаг. 3 л. наст. и буд.). Выражает приказание, пожелание, призыв; **пусть**.

Розенталь:  Подпустить врага и огонь дать по команде! (Фурм.) — **объединяет побудительная интонация**; Пусть кончится холод и наступит тепло! — объединяет побудительная частица; Да будет свято имя героя и память о нём сохранится в веках! — объединяет **побудительная частица.**

В нашем случае **побудительным является только второе предложение**, к нему же, скорее всего, относится и восклицание.

И немного об интонации. Разве можно это предложение прочитать в одну фразу, не сделав паузу. А ведь отсутствие запятой говорит именно о таком прочтении.

Answer (score 0):

Запятая нужна, так как это сложносочиненное предложение. Союз "и" Вас смутил, так как чаще он используется в перечислении однородных членов предложения (в случае двух членов предложения или в случае нескольких членов предложения, где последние два перечисляются не через запятую, а посредством союза "и"), где запятая как раз не ставится. Рассматриваемый случай не является перечислением. Для наглядности перефразировать предложение можно так:

> Желаю Вам удачи, пусть Бог помогает.

Comment: Но это ведь два восклицательных предложения, следовательно, запятая не нужна. Или я что-то путаю?